# Infer a Python function definition statement by performing a static analysis on its body

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working in [CoNaLa dataset](https://github.com/conala-corpus/conala-corpus.github.io) contains high-quality natural language intent and source code snippet pairs in Python. The data are stored in JSON format, and you can see some examples below:

```
{
  "example": 1,
  "intent": "copying one file's contents to another in python", 
  "snippet": "shutil.copy(source_file, target_file)", 
},

{
  "example": 2
  "intent": "How do I check if all elements in a list are the same?", 
  "snippet": "len(set(mylist)) == 1", 
}

{
  "example": 3
  "intent": "Iterate through words of a file in Python", 
  "snippet": "words = open(my_file).read().split()"
}
```

I am looking for an approach to encapsulate each of the code snippets into a function. However to accomplish that I would have to infer which parameters this function should contain. In example 1, for instance, function declaration could be:

```
def function_name (source_file, target_file):
```

where `function_name` can be a generic name but the parameters should be `source_file` and `target_file` because they must be known in `shutil.copy` method.

For examples 2 and 3 the expected result would be respectively:

```
def function_name (myList):
```

and

```
def function_name (my_file):
```

Comment: Terminology nitpick: Python *doesn't have function declarations*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, what is the name of the function name together with the parameters e.g.: 'def func_name (param1, param2):?

Comment: It's a function definition statement

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you.

Comment: @JohnColeman, I tried to make it clear what I intend to achieve.

Comment: Getting argument names from `shutil.copy(source_file, target_file)` is straight parsing. The `ast` module should be able to handle it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16635254/4996248) seems related.